# F# match pattern discriminator not defined issue

Tags: list, recursion, error-handling, f#, pattern-matching

im in the process of writing a transposing recursive function and i have stopped at a problem. So i want to have a check using match by calling isTable function to verify that the input M is a valid table, however it errors and im not sure how to fix it

```
let isTable list =
    match List.map List.length list |> List.distinct |> List.length with
    | 1 -> true
    | _ -> false


let rec transpose M = 
    match M with 
    | []::_ -> []
    | (isTable M) -> [] // i want to check here if M is a valid table
    | _ ->  (List.map List.head M::transpose(List.map List.tail M))
```

*error FS0039: The pattern discriminator 'isTable' is not defined.*

Comment: Look up Active Patterns which actually do this. In fact the compiler is complaining that it can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
let rec transpose M = 
    match M with 
    | []::_ -> []
    | _ -> match (isTable M)  with
       | true - > [] // i want to check here if M is a valid table
       | _ ->  (List.map List.head M::transpose(List.map List.tail M))
```

As a matter of programming style I'd recommend adding a data constructor like `Table` so that you *can* match on it but this should get things working.

Answer (score 7):

Active patterns are one approach, but the overhead of adding one just for a single use is not worth it. An easy and uncluttered solution would be to use a when clause:

```
let rec transpose M = 
    match M with 
    | []::_ -> []
    | _ when isTable M -> []
    | _ ->  (List.map List.head M::transpose(List.map List.tail M))
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers yet show how to turn your case into an *Active Pattern*. This is particularly useful for (1) readability and (2) reusability of code. Assuming you'd need `isTable` more than once, this can be beneficial.

```
/// Active pattern, must start with capital letter.
let (|IsTable|_|) list =
    match List.map List.length list |> List.distinct with
    | [_] -> Some list
    | _ -> None


let rec transpose M = 
    match M with 
    | []::_ -> []
    | IsTable M -> []    // using the active pattern
    | _ ->  
        List.map List.head M::transpose(List.map List.tail M)
```

As an aside, your `isTable` function matched over `List.length` result. A `List.length` iterates over the whole list and is `O(n)`. Since we're only interested if the result is one item, the above approach will be more efficient, removing at least one iteration from the code.